# How can write to a text file keys and values and read them back?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a new form i did

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            label1.Text = "Updating Settings File";
            label1.Visible = true;
            w = new StreamWriter(AuthenticationFileName,true);
            w.WriteLine(cTextBox1.Text);
            w.Close();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button4.Enabled = false;
            label1.Text = "Updating Settings File";
            label1.Visible = true;
            w = new StreamWriter(AuthenticationFileName,true);
            w.WriteLine(cTextBox2.Text);
            w.Close();
            timer1.Start();
        }
```

Then in form1:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Authentication.AuthenticationFileName);
apiKey = lines[0];
userid = lines[1];
jsonfiledirectory = lines[2];
```

But the problem is that there might be cases the apiKey,userid and jsonfiledirectory will not be the same order like now [0] [1] [2]
So instead just make WriteLine i want to add a key and a value to each line for example the text file will be like this:

```
apikey = 435345erfsefs54
userid = myttt@walla.com
jsonfiledirectory = c:\
```

So when i read back the text file no matter the order of the lines.

Comment: Post is missing explanation of what you have problem with - please consider adding one (clearly it is not writing or reading, it is also unlikely that you are asking for string splitting or comparison). Side note: Inventing file formats is traditional programmers' past time - one you trying to create is sometimes called [ini file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) (link also gives you code)...

Comment: ini is quite old as approach, i think that moving to JSON is probably better and quite easy as shown on my answer. Another try could be to use .config appSettings to store those info, but i think that json is the easier one

Comment: A good option for windows forms is creating `.settings` files using designer or create a setting class inheriting `ApplicationSettingsBase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to save settings including xml serializing your class, using ini files, using registry, using json files, using appsettings, ... .

One of good approaches for a windows forms application is using [Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx).

This way you can create settings class using designer or using code and then at run-time, load settings, change values and save or reset settings.

**To create settings using designer:**

1. In Solution Explorer, expand the Properties node of your project and open `Settings.settings` or add a new setting file if you need.
2. In the designer for each setting that you need, you can set the `Name` of setting, `Value` as default value, `Type` for the setting and choose `User` as scope. This way you can change the setting at run-time.
3. You can read values, change them or save settings this way:

```
//Read and show a value
MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.Key1);

//Changes the value
Properties.Settings.Default.Key1 = "New Value";

//Save settings (You can do it in a setting form or in close event of your main form)
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**To create settings programmatically:**

1. Add a class to the project and name it `MySettings` and inherit from [`System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Add properties for each application setting you need. Add [`UserScopedSettingAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.userscopedsettingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to the property. You can also provide a default value for that property using [DefaultSettingValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.defaultsettingvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
public class MySettings : System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue("Value1")]
    public string Key1
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)this["Key1"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["Key1"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when using, you can

```
MySettings settnigs;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    settnigs= new MySettings ();

    //Read and show a value
    MessageBox.Show(settnigs.Key1);

    //Changes the value
    settnigs.Key1 = "New Value";
}

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs 
{
    settnigs.Save();
}
```

To learn more about settings:

- [Application Settings Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

what about using Json.Net ( http://www.newtonsoft.com/json ), create a class that hold your property you want to serialize/deserialize then using Json.Net to handle them?

it's pretty easy, I've done a fiddle for you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lkkLUv

basically create a class like

```
public class Settings {
    public string ApiKey { get; set;}
    public string UserId { get; set;}
    public string JsonFileDirectory { get; set;}
}
```

then read it (the file of course need to be formatted properly in json)

```
Settings settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(settingsExample);
```

where settingsExample contains the string read from file (you can use json to read directly from file if you want)

to save, just use JsonConvert.Serialize(settings) to get the string and save it to the file you want