# Create a config or INI file to store user settings preferences

Tags: c#, winforms, config, ini

I wrote an application that can be ran in two different modes: test or not. I also have the ability to trace according to a flag. I would like to have a config or INI file to set those flags in order to prevent changing the code every time I want to set those flags. I am not sure how to make it.
Do I need to add new item: application config file through visual studio? Or do I need to create a INI file? Will it let me to change the values from the installation folder without having to change the code?

I tried to add an application config file to the project but I am not able to set my own values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <userSettings>
      <add key="TestEnvironment" value="true" />
      <add key="Tracing" value="true" />
   </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am getting 7 warnings:
the main one is: Could not find schema information for the element userSettings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **appSettings** element to store your key-value pairs:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TestEnvironment" value="true" />
    <add key="Tracing" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And in the application you can read them like this:

```
bool testEnv = bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestEnvironment"]);
bool tracing = bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tracing"]);
```

(Make sure you have System.Configuration added to your references)

Comment: Yes you can use AppSettings or as another (better) solution,  use `Settings` files. Probably you will find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34159904/3110834) about creating and using settings helpful. Is also supports [property binding to application settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34483981/3110834).

Comment: If I understanding right, on each computer that the application is installed, I will be able to change rom the file system the values of those properties and it will affect the code, right? DO I need to set the Copy To Output Directory to True for that?

Comment: @ehh: You can change the values manually on the config file, but then you need to restart the application for those changes to take affect. When you compile VS automatically creates the a config file named after your application. For instance, if your project is MyApp, it generates MyApp.exe.config. So you don't see App.config in the output folder anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can go to the project properties and into the Configuration tab. There you can add as many settings as you want and Visual Studio will add them to an automated app.config config file.

Using this system you can access your settings from the code using the name you gave them in the config file like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName
```

Comment: Or you can find it under properties folder or add your settings file using designer or code. Probably you will find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34159904/3110834) about creating and using settings helpful.

Comment: I added as you suggested a user setting through the project properties and I am getting warning as I wrote in my post. I am working with VS2015